# Need help setting a background image in my bootstrap/angular beginners web app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Newbie question: I've created a github page for one of my projects

http://grokimagecompression.github.io/grok/#/

by copying a tutorial from the web, and modifying it .

The source can be found here:

https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/tree/gh-pages

I would like to set a background image, similar to how this page does it:

http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/

but so far have had no luck. The image is `img/header.jpg` in my gh-pages branch.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is setting a backgroud image on the body not an option for you? you'd have to change text contrasts though as the image is quite dark.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to the css

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

    background: url("img/header.jpg") no-repeat center cover;

}
```

For more information about  background check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the image didn't show up.

Comment: @jacko have you checked the network log in the browser to ensure the browser is requesting it from the correct location ie, it's loading?

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?